# Windows Server 2003 not loading web pages by domain, but loads/pings by IP (Server not found)

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, domain, ip-address

It's really weird and randomly started happening..

Example:

I open firefox or IE on the server and try to load "google.com". It doesn't load. Pinging it doesn't work either.

However, if it use the IP to ping or open it in firefox or IE, it works. The IP of the site google, 74.125.227.121.

It's not just google, it's every website.

It's not a firewall issue..

Comment: The answer is in your tags: DNS.

Answer (score 1):

As John points out. Its almost certainly something to do with your DNS settings. If you issue ipconfig /all from the command line, it should tell you what the IP address of your DNS server(s) which may be your router, depending on your setup.